# Would Blitzer's "Algebra and Trigonometry" book be sufficient for advanced algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm looking to develop a more intimate understanding of mathematics, and I never developed further than Algebra I. Would a book like Blitzer's "Algebra and Trigonometry" cover Algebra II? Does it cover linear algebra? And is it overall sufficient for an understanding of algebra, or will one require more textbooks for the subject?

Comment: i debt that most people here are familiar with specific texts. Same for the content of courses that may be standard where you live, but not elsewhere.

Comment: It's very difficult to self-learn mathematics. I recommend taking a course.Try [this](https://www.edx.org/course/a-level-mathematics-for-y12).

Comment: Even the naming of the courses vary: At least in my country, Algebra I and II are typically university courses for the second year and come *after* linear algebra. In all cases, you will rarely find recommendations on books that are not absolute and international standard (and introductory textbooks rarely are, because in many countries basic studies are done in the respective language).